# Can I change the keystore path or i will never be able to update my app?

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

Can I change the path of my keystore folder on my computer, or will that affect my ability to further update my app on the play store?

Comment: Put it wherever you want, just use the exact same one for updating the app in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to the keystore it is not relevat. What's important is the keystore (**.jks**) file along with it´s credentials.

If you forgot your credentials or you've lost your keystore, maybe there´s a chance you can upload a new signing keystore to Google.

According to [App Singnig by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en), those are the steps needed (copy-paste from mentioned site):

#### Create an upload key & update keystores

For increased security, signing your app with a new upload key, instead of your app signing key, is recommended.

You can create an upload key when you opt in to app signing by Google Play, or you can create an upload key later by visiting Release management > App signing.

Here’s how to create an upload key:

1- Follow the instructions on the Android Developers site. Store your key in a safe place.

2- Export the certificate for the upload key to PEM format. Replace the following underlined arguments:

`$ keytool -export -rfc -keystore upload-keystore.jks -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem`

3- When prompted during the release process, upload the certificate to register it with Google.

**When you use an upload key:**

- Your upload key is only registered with Google to authenticate the identity of the app creator.
- Your signature is removed from any uploaded APKs before they’re sent to users.